# Parse specific path with xpath (Nokogiri)

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a rails service reading an XML from a SOAP endpoint. The simplified structure is like:

```
<resource id="1287085300000102889" ...>
  <prices>
   <price datefrom="2018-05-25" dateto="2018-05-26" price="0.0" currency="EUR"/>
   <price datefrom="2020-05-23" dateto="2020-05-24" price="1540.0" currency="EUR"/>
   ...
  </prices>
  <products>
    <product name="product1">
      <prices>
        <price datefrom="2018-05-25" dateto="2018-05-26" price="0.0" currency="EUR"/>
        <price datefrom="2020-05-23" dateto="2020-05-24" price="1540.0" currency="EUR"/>
      </prices>
    </product>
  </products>
</resource>
```

I´m parsing the information using Nokogiri gem that I think uses xpath. 
In the example above, I´m using `resource.xpath(".//price")` but this is processing all prices.I just want to parse the prices inside the "default" prices node  and I don´t want to process the prices inside each product. How can I do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the XPath you want is `.//resource/prices/price` but it's not clear from your question what the context, represented by the `.` in your path, is.